# How to solve Closure: () => int in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a case like this and I don't understand why this is happening, because the console does not give an error message.

I want to sum up the data in the API but the output is as follows.

[image]

Here I do the sum

```
int getSum() {
int? uts = int.tryParse(data.first.nilaiIndeksUts ?? '');
int? akhir = int.tryParse(data.first.nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '');
return (uts ?? 0) + (akhir ?? 0);
}
```

I call getSum in here

```
Text(
'$getSum',
style: bold6,
),
```

and this is the model I made from API, I still haven't found the solution for days.
Has anyone here ever experienced a similar case or have done a summation of data in the API?
Thank you in advance.

```
class NilaiMahasiswa {
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Data>? data;

  NilaiMahasiswa({this.status, this.code, this.data});

  NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['code'] = code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? idTranskripNilai;
  String? idMk;
  String? kodeMk;
  String? nmMk;
  int? sks;
  int? smt;
  String? nilaiAkhirUts;
  String? nilaiHurufUts;
  String? nilaiIndeksUts;
  String? nilaiAkhirUas;
  String? nilaiAkhir;
  String? nilaiHurufAkhir;
  String? nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiUts;
  String? updatedBy;

  Data(
      {this.idTranskripNilai,
      this.idMk,
      this.kodeMk,
      this.nmMk,
      this.sks,
      this.smt,
      this.nilaiAkhirUts,
      this.nilaiHurufUts,
      this.nilaiIndeksUts,
      this.nilaiAkhirUas,
      this.nilaiAkhir,
      this.nilaiHurufAkhir,
      this.nilaiIndeksAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiUts,
      this.updatedBy});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idTranskripNilai = json['id_transkrip_nilai'];
    idMk = json['id_mk'];
    kodeMk = json['kode_mk'];
    nmMk = json['nm_mk'];
    sks = json['sks'];
    smt = json['smt'];
    nilaiAkhirUts = json['nilai_akhir_uts'];
    nilaiHurufUts = json['nilai_huruf_uts'];
    nilaiIndeksUts = json['nilai_indeks_uts'];
    nilaiAkhirUas = json['nilai_akhir_uas'];
    nilaiAkhir = json['nilai_akhir'];
    nilaiHurufAkhir = json['nilai_huruf_akhir'];
    nilaiIndeksAkhir = json['nilai_indeks_akhir'];
    statusNilaiAkhir = json['status_nilai_akhir'];
    statusNilaiUts = json['status_nilai_uts'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id_transkrip_nilai'] = idTranskripNilai;
    data['id_mk'] = idMk;
    data['kode_mk'] = kodeMk;
    data['nm_mk'] = nmMk;
    data['sks'] = sks;
    data['smt'] = smt;
    data['nilai_akhir_uts'] = nilaiAkhirUts;
    data['nilai_huruf_uts'] = nilaiHurufUts;
    data['nilai_indeks_uts'] = nilaiIndeksUts;
    data['nilai_akhir_uas'] = nilaiAkhirUas;
    data['nilai_akhir'] = nilaiAkhir;
    data['nilai_huruf_akhir'] = nilaiHurufAkhir;
    data['nilai_indeks_akhir'] = nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_akhir'] = statusNilaiAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_uts'] = statusNilaiUts;
    data['updated_by'] = updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `getSum` anywhere.

Comment: i've update this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getSum` is a function, you need to add `()` to call it and return `integer` value.

```
Text( '${getSum()}', style: bold6,),
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the following error message
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zI91O8b55vC19ShtwcLuzCFJTCUU1MJY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you added `{ }` as well? `${getSum()}`

Comment: yes, like the example you gave

Comment: I'm sorry, it worked.
but the results of the sum do not match.
do you know why?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ugXz4ZmRLalygsf71X-7am2SALRCCDEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can debug it using `print` inside `getSum()` function and make sure the value is correct.

Comment: error Stack Overflow, if i run print

Comment: How did you write the code to print the value?

Comment: print(getSum());

Comment: I mean, you can print the value you sum (uts and akhir) and make sure they are the values ​​you expect.

Comment: it's appropriate but I can't add up the (uts) and also the (akhir)